# Higlight files which are not from my repository

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes I open files from directories, which are not in my workspace.

Example:

```
❯ rg 'func newCloud' ..

../talos-cloud-controller-manager/pkg/talos/cloud.go:46:1:func newCloud(config *cloudConfig) (cloudprovider.Interface, error) {
...
```

Then I open `../talos-cloud-controller-manager/pkg/talos/cloud.go`.

Unfortunately there is not immediately visible if a file is from the workspace, or from outside.

[image: vs-code-file-from-outside-workspace]

Is there a way to highlight it somehow, so that you immediately see that a file does not belong to the current workspace?

In above screenshot there are two small indicators. See "talos", but I would like to have a more visible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just released a new extension, [Highlight Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.highlight-files), to color the tabs and Explorer labels of non-workspace files.  I have more to do but in the meantime if you drop a non-workspace file or file open a non-workspace color the tab will get colored lime green.

That color is configurable in your `settings.json`:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "highlightFiles.nonWorkspaceFiles": "#91ff00",  // any hex color you want
    // #91ff0060 - last two digits are opacity
}
```

There are these settings:

[image: settings for the extension Highlight Files]

```
Highlight Files > Decorations > Enable: Color   (in the Settings UI), default is false

"highlightFiles.decorations.enable.color": true/false   in settings.json
```

The above default is `false`, so you will have to opt-in to enable the extension and start coloring tab names.  You can change the setting at any time and it should take effect immediately.

```
Highlight Files > Decorations > Enable: Badges   (in the Settings UI), default is false  

"highlightFiles.decorations.enable.badges": true/false   in settings.json
```

The defaults for colors and badges are `false`, so you will have to opt-in to enable the extension and start adding badges and colors to tab names.  You can change these setting at any time and they should take effect immediately.

```
Highlight Files > Decorations : Badge   (in the Settings UI), default is `!``

"highlightFiles.decorations.badge": string, 1-2 characters
```

[image: demo of decorating non-workspace files]

The badge can only be **string** of 1-2 letters, but unicode works too.

Note that `settings.json` is not a workspace file and thus is colored.  Should I filter out `settings.json, keybindings.json, and similar` from being colored?  [I have filtered them out for now... so they are not colored]

Comment: I think it would be great, if the background color of that file would change. No drastic change, just a bit different, since I usualy don't look at the top (tab).

Comment: I would color settings.json and keybindings.json, too. But I would not use red color by default. You could use the  symbol instead of "!!" since the file is "outside".

Comment: It isn't possible to change the background color of individual files, not even the background color of the tabs (other than the active one) - unfortunately there is no api to make such changes.  The `outside` icon is cute but at the very small size it wouldn't render well - it has to be something pretty simple.

Comment: Latest version is v0.0.4.  There is a setting to enable, it is false by default - see edited answer above.  Also the badge at the end of the file label must be a string of 1-2 characters, including unicode.

Comment: vscode does not allow to change the background color of individual files? That's a missing feature. Is there already a Github issue for this?

Comment: I believe I have seen issues about changing the background color of the active editor, probably on the backlog.  Not sure about changing the color based on other criteria, like language or source.  The extension is up to v0.0.5.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165934 about background colors of active editors.  And by filetype: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20652.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine. If I were you, I would enable the setting "Enable Color" by default.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty!  I will probably change the default of the extension.  Are you using any badge?  Do you think that should default enable or disabled?

Comment: yes I use the  badge :-). I would enable it by default. I think it is a good indicator for "outside".